# What is the difference between electrons and energy?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, microbiology

I'm studying microbiology right now and I have come across something confusing to me. I thought electrons provided energy to the cell by being incorporated into reducing powers and eventually driving the synthesis of ATP. However in classification of microbes energy sources (photo, chemo) and electron sources (litho, organo) are separate.

Is there a scenario in which the source of electrons and energy are different (besides phototrophy)?

Comment: This is not a biological question and if you are studying microbiology, then you would have also learnt basic physics. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology but basic physics.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question hidden here, but the formulation is throwing us off. Something on the lines of which energy sources does the cell use other than redox reactions of ATP. We could try translating "what does energy do that electrons can't do" as "what do other cellular energy sources do that ATP synthesis/cleaving can't" or something similar.

Comment: @rumtscho I still cannot understand what the actual question is. I am interpretting it like this — how different sources of energy translate to ATP production?

Comment: Electrons and Energy are 2 completely different thing. Electron is a class of **negatively-charged sub-atomic particle**. Energy is a concept, that is **"ability of a system to do some work"**. You could consider it as "unstability" of a system

Comment: A system, contain the more energy, the more it is prone to do a work, the more it is unstable, the more it is prone to achieve someother more-stable conformation. Such as if you keep a spring relaxed, it contains a less-amount of energy. But if you press or extend or bend it than its normal-conformation; it contains more energy. If you release it, the energy comes out and perform certain work, say shot a bullet.

Comment: Just like pressing a spring cause a change in its energy-level; any change in a molecule's structure (bonding) (chemical-change) and conformation (in simple language, shape-change without change in bond-connectivity) (many of the physical-changes); cause change in energy level.

Comment: Chemical change occur due to change in electronic configuration of atoms

Comment: Since living-creatures made up of atoms; the biological works (requiring energy), take place through chemical-change (i.e. electron-configuration change.). But electron is not same as energy.

Comment: Sometime for ease of stoichiometric (chemical-arithmetic) calculations, the number of certain chemical-species (say electron, H+, NADPH, NAD, ATP, etc are considered as a packet, containing certain amount of energy, in certain particular pathways or processes). But they are not themselves energy. The are matter

Comment: Question is closed. So I couldn't answer. Read my 6 successive comment above as an answer. You need to understand well enough the basic school-level chemistry and physics before learning advanced science. However, no question is bad, rather avoiding ask question is bad.

Answer (score 9):

You're basically confusing the fuel source with the energy it produces. For example, a car burns gasoline. That doesn't mean that gasoline is energy, only that gasoline can be *used* to produce energy. Similarly, a cell uses electrons in the production of ATP ([source](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/sciences/biology/biochemistry-i/oxidative-phosphorylation/atp-synthesis)):

[image: ATP synthesis]

In the image above, electrons (symbolized by the flat arrow going from $\mathit{NADH}$ + $H^+$ to $\frac{1}{2}O_2$ + $2H^+$) flow from NADH-Q reductase (I) to cytochrome reductase (III), to cytochrome oxidase (IV). The electron flow across these complexes causes the pumping of hydrogen cations (protons) through the membrane to the extracellular space. This, in turn, produces a pH gradient and membrane potential which are used to drive the synthesis of ATP (by the $F_1F_0$ ATPase), which can be broken down to release energy ([source](http://greatneck.k12.ny.us/GNPS/SHS/dept/science/krauz/bio_h/images/08_09ATPHydrolysis_L.jpg)):

[image: ATP hydrolysis]

So, electrons are needed<sup>1</sup> to produce ATP and ATP can be thought of as energy storage. When ATP is broken down to produce AMP and Phosphate, energy is released in the form of heat. This is why ATP is considered as "energy currency". Neither ATP nor electrons, however, are "energy" themselves<sup>2</sup>. No more than gasoline is.

---

<sup>1</sup> Are *used*, anyway. There are other choices.

<sup>2</sup> No more than any other form of matter, at least. You can, actually, think of matter as condensed energy but that is really squarely in the realm of physics and not biology.